# PHP if/then to display link

Tags: php, url, if-statement, echo

I'm trying to display a "log in" / "log out" link. I want to display the log in link if they are not logged in, etc.  I'm having trouble getting this to work.  Heres what I've been trying:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) 
 { ?> <a href="logout.php">Log out</a><?php } ?>
<?php
else 
{ ?> <a href="login.php">Log In</a>  <?php } ?>
```

Basically, if the assess_token is set, it will show a link to log out.  And if not, a log in link.  I keep getting this as an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

And i've tried this variation:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) 
{ echo "<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>" }
else 
{ echo "<a href="login.p">Log In</a>" } ?>
```

which get me:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

what am i missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: It looks like you're missing semi-colons after the `echo` statements

Comment: That "duplicate" is certainly the Mother-of-all-PHP-Error-Questions.  However, it does not mention either error message (no mention of T_ELSE or T_STRING).  This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting an error in the first example, but I'd go with the second form -- much easier to read. Once you correct the issue identified by @Carpetsmoker, you should be good to go.

Comment: I think the problem of the first example is the `?><?php` before the **else** - The PHP intepreter cant handle that. Try it: `if($test) {} ?><?php else {} ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 examples and both have syntax errors:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE
```

If you **format your code** correctly, you found the error:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        ?> <a href="logout.php">Log out</a><?php
    } else {
        ?> <a href="login.php">Log In</a> <?php
    }
?>
```

That:

```
<?php } ?>
<?php
else 
{ ?>
```

is not valid. The PHP intepreter can't handle this! Please use `<?php } else { ?>`

The second: Use an Syntax-Highlighted editor! You see that the Syntax is not correct.
Escape the `"` in your code, you forgotten the `;` after the echo:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Log out</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"login.php\">Log In</a>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's normal . look at your echo . There are only double quotes. You have to use (for example) double quotes for echo, and single quotes to delimit logout.php and login.php

```
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>";
```

Comment: Plus, though your example shows a `;`, the OP's code does not have that either.